# I can't put a solid region to bottom layer and there is a violation which I couldn't figured out

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

Below, you can see there is a rule violation which is related to clearance. I changed the clearance to 0mm it is gone but I believe there must be some clearance. How can I eliminate this problem? Secondly, I'm not able to put a solid region neiter to top layer nor bottom layer. Only there occur a grid as you can see in the image. If someone has encountered such problems, please guide me. (I'm using Altium Designer 20 btw). [image]

[image]

Comment: did you assign a net to the polygon to be the same as the pads (NETL1_1)?

Comment: yeah I tried that and nets connected to each other but this time a little gap (maybe neck IDK) occured between pad and polygon. however, I want to use solid region option.

Comment: that may because of polygon connection rules. In the pcb rules and conditions window, there is a section for polygon, have you tried this? Does the current rule look like the gap you described?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I went to Design>Rules>Plane>polygon connect style>direct connect and problem solved however I'm still curious why solid region is not working. BTW thanks for your guidance HV16

Comment: what happens when you replace this polygon with a solid region?

Comment: A grid is occured but it is not a piece of copper it just stays there. it doesnt make connects between nets. And also it creates a violation like "Clearance constrait (collision <0.254mm) Between Polyregion on BottomLayer and pad on multilayer/bottomlayer". But when I drop clearance to 0mm problem goes away. but I think reducing clearance is not the solution. thats are my observation for this problem.

Comment: This sounds exactly the same as the problem you had with the polygon. Did you assign a net to this solid region? If copper and pads are overlapping, they have to have the same net, i.e. connected together; otherwise, this is considered short-circuited which results in a violation

Answer (score 1):

The region shown in the above 2nd screensnap is a keepout. Need to use a solid copper region so can assign net.